# XML Reader threw Object Null exception, but node exists(?!)

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

I am hoping someone could enlighten me as to why I am getting the annoying - "xml object reference not set to an instance .." error.

The elements (nodes?) I am looking for seem to exist and I have not misspelled it either :[

I might be doing something stupid here, but any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

My Code:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    XmlDocument reader = new XmlDocument();
    reader.Load("Kotaku - powered by FeedBurner.xml");
    XmlNodeList titles = reader.GetElementsByTagName("title");
    XmlNodeList dates = reader.GetElementsByTagName("pubDate"); 
    XmlNodeList descriptions = reader.GetElementsByTagName("description");
    XmlNodeList links = reader.GetElementsByTagName("link"); 
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.Count; i++)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + titles[i].InnerText);
        textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + descriptions[i].InnerText); //<<-- Throws Object Ref Null Exception
        textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + links[i].InnerText);
        textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + dates[i].InnerText); //<<-- Throws Object Ref Null Exception

    }  

}
```

The XML I am using is a saved XML page from: http://feeds.gawker.com/kotaku/full

The way I am working on it now is as follows: I have saved the page from the above link (which is an XML page) and put it next to my EXE for easier access.
Then I run the code.

Comment: At what line does the exception occur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that you read RSS is wrong. First get all the items and loop though each item and build the text. Better if you can use `StringBuilder` and finally convert it to string. 
Before access properties of an object you can check for null.

```
XmlDocument RSSXml = new XmlDocument();
RSSXml.Load("Kotaku - powered by FeedBurner.xml");
XmlNodeList RSSNodeList = RSSXml.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (XmlNode RSSNode in RSSNodeList)
{
    XmlNode RSSSubNode;
    RSSSubNode = RSSNode.SelectSingleNode("title");
    string title = RSSSubNode != null ? RSSSubNode.InnerText : "";
    RSSSubNode = RSSNode.SelectSingleNode("link");
    string link = RSSSubNode != null ? RSSSubNode.InnerText : "";
    RSSSubNode = RSSNode.SelectSingleNode("description");
    string desc = RSSSubNode != null ? RSSSubNode.InnerText : "";
    RSSSubNode = RSSNode.SelectSingleNode("pubDate");
    string pubDate = RSSSubNode != null ? RSSSubNode.InnerText : "";
    sb.Append("<font face='arial'><p><b><a href='");
    sb.Append(link);
    sb.Append("'>");
    sb.Append(title);
    sb.Append("</a></b><br/>");
    sb.Append(desc);
    sb.Append(pubDate);
    sb.Append("</p></font>");
}
textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Ah, so this is why i was doing it wrong.. Thank you very much for the nudge in the right direction. I've studied this a little and the logic of it is quite clear :) Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

It cannot run in for loop because number of items in titles, descriptions, links and dates was (at the time when I ran it) respectively: 39 38 39 37.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the source of http://feeds.gawker.com/kotaku/full.

What I see - in the HMTL source at least - there is a `<title>` element in the channel header too. Which not belongs to any item yet. Isn't it possible, that your code count some additional elements like this when you use `title.Count` as the limit of your `for` cicle?

If that is the case, it is possible, that you wont have enough elements in the other arrays in your loop. Did you check this too?